# Get selected option on edit form in laravel

Tags: laravel, select, edit

This is my code; the problem is its show the default value not the one in the database

```
<select name="Lieu" id="Lieu" class="dropdown"  required>
                               <option value="Rabat"  {{ ($emps->Lieu) == 'Rabat' ? 'selected' : '' }}  >Rabat</option>
                                <option value="Témara" {{ ($emps->Lieu) == 'Témara' ? 'selected' : '' }}  >Témara</option>
                                <option value="Salé"  {{ ($emps->Lieu) == 'Salé' ? 'selected' : '' }} >Salé</option>
                              </select>
```

Comment: yes its correct

Answer (score 0):

Remove bracket from condition

```
<select name="Lieu" id="Lieu" class="dropdown"  required>
    <option value="Rabat"  {{ $emps->Lieu == 'Rabat' ? 'selected' : '' }}  >Rabat</option>
    <option value="Témara" {{ $emps->Lieu == 'Témara' ? 'selected' : '' }}  >Témara</option>
    <option value="Salé"   {{ $emps->Lieu == 'Salé' ? 'selected' : '' }} >Salé</option>
</select>
```

Comment: its still show the deffault value :(